# Django automatically set foreign key in form (with class based views)

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to use a form to generate a new object (say a Book) from a Person's page such that the new Book is automatically associated with that Person via a foreign key, but I am running into trouble getting the Person correctly associated and saved with the form. For my models, I have:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    p_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)

class Book(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I then have a custom form to create a Book:

```
class AddBookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title', 'person',)
        widgets = {
            'person': forms.HiddenInput,
        }
```

And a view to create the Book (which is also given the `pk` (`p_id`) of the Person):

```
class AddBook(CreateView):
    model = Book
```

I have tried various things to get this to work:

- Pre-populating the Person field with `get_initial`, but this disappears for some reason with the input is set to hidden (frustratingly).
- modifying the `form_valid` method in the view, but this only occurs after the form has already been validated, so I need to add Person before that.
- modifying the `clean_person` method in the form class, but that only occurs after the form has been validated by the `clean` method.

Currently, I am trying to override the `clean` method. However, I don't know how to get the Person at this point, after the form has already been sent for cleaning. In the view, I could access it with `Patient.objects.get(p_id=self.kwargs.get('pk'))`.

Is there some way I can add the data to the form in my view (as a class-based view) that it won't get stripped away **OR** is there some way I can access the Person or `p_id` foreign key at this point to add the data in the `clean` method?

Comment: How do you know which person to associate the book with if the user is not selecting it?

Comment: They click "create book" on a Person's page and the id of that page is sent with the request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're going at it the wrong way: the person is not user input, so this information should not reside in the form. You can override the `form_valid` method as follows:

```
class AddBook(CreateView):
    model = Book

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.person_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(AddBook, self).form_valid(form)
```

This will set the `person_id` attribute on the instance used by the form to save the data, and then call the `super` method to save that instance and return a redirect.

Comment: I had tried *almost* that. There were 2 tricks, though: I had to take that field out of the form so it would validate, and I had been trying `form.instance.p_id` instead of `person_id`. I still don't totally understand why it's `person_id.` The `person` part I get, because that's the field name. but why `_id`? Is that just the equivalent of `pk` in that context?

Comment: Yes: a foreign key always consists of two attributes; the foreign object (a model instance), and the foreign key (the primary key of the referenced object). The foreign key attribute always has `_id` appended to the name of the foreign model attribute, and this is the field that is actually saved to the database. And indeed, you have to take the field out of the form.

Comment: Note in Python 3, calls to [`super`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super) can be simplified to `super()`

Answer (score 4):

Since the ID is sent with the request, your form does not need a person field.  Instead, you need to add the person before the Book is saved.

Your form should be:

```
class BookForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('title',)
```

Your views should be something like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

def create_book(request, person_id):

     # If the person_id is not valid, don't go forward.
     # return a 404 instead.

     person = get_object_or_404(Person, pk=person_id)

     book_form = BookForm(request.POST or None)
     if book_form.is_valid():
         new_book = book_form.save(commit=False) # Don't save it yet
         new_book.person = person # Add person
         new_book.save() # Now save it
         return redirect('/')

     return render(request, 'book_form.html', {'form': book_form})
```

In your `urls.py`, make sure you are passing the id to this view:

```
url(r'book/add/(?P<person_id>\d+)/$', create_book, name='create_book')
```

You would call it like this `http://localhost:8000/book/add/1/` (if you are adding for person id 1).

You also don't need to give your own primary key, django will add one by default to all models, so your `Person` model should be simply:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) # Or some other field
```

Now, your person model will have an automatic `pk` property, which will be the primary key (whatever it is actually called in your database).

Comment: This is a very NOT classed based view ;)

Comment: Came up with same question, what if he would need to do some logic based on that peraon instance? In your way the person would not be available in form clean() methods