# Django nested admin: how to set foreign key to grandparents'id?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

I have a django project where I use [nested-admin](https://github.com/theatlantic/django-nested-admin), and I'm trying to figure out how to set the foreign key of an element to its grandparents' id.

I have the following `model.py`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)


class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, null=True)
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

`Project`'s FK to `Job` can be NULL for the simple reason that a project is not necessarily related to a Job (i.e. personal project).

`admin.py`:

```
class ProjectInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Project
    extra = 1


class JobInline(NestedStackedInline):
    model = Job
    inlines = [ProjectInline]
    extra = 1


@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(NestedModelAdmin):
    model = Person
    inlines = [JobInline]
```

Currently, the `Person` form looks like this:

[image: Current look. See Person field[2]]

The fact that we can choose the `Person` in `Project` doesn't make any sense. I want to attach it directly to the `Job`'s person.

I believe I have to customize a form or a view, and looked into `UpdateView` (like [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813496/django-automatically-set-foreign-key-in-form-with-class-based-views)), but I haven't manage to do what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer to the question asked

I managed to get something working using the [nested_admin](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline/blob/master/nested_inline/admin.py#L45) source code.

First, exclude the `person` field from the `project` form:

```
class ProjectInline(NestedStackedInline):
    # [...]

    exclude = ["person"]
```

In `PersonAdmin`, add the following code:

```
def save_formset(self, request, form, formset, change):

    for form in formset.forms:
        for job_form in form.nested_formsets:
            job_form.instance.person = form.instance.person
            for project_form in job_form:
                project_form.instance.person = form.instance.person

    super(PersonAdmin, self).save_formset(request, form, formset, change)
```

This way, the `person` field won't be displayed, preventing the user to change it, and it will automatically be set to the same value as the `Job`'s `Person` you're modifying.

#### New problem appears!

However, another problem will appear if you try to add `ProjectInline` to `Person`:

[image: The problem you'll encounter]

As you can see, the Project "website" is both displayed inside the Job subset and the Person.

#### Best solution

After a lot of work, you will probably manage to do exactly what you want.

But in my opinion, the *easiest* solution would be to create **two** different `Project` model, both inheriting from the same base. You'd have a `PersonnalProject`, with a FK to `Person`, and a `JobProject`, with a FK to `Job`.

It will take more place in database but is so much easier to handle afterwards.