# Django: automatically assigning foreign key in CBV form

Tags: django

This builds on: [Django automatically set foreign key in form (with class based views)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24813496/django-automatically-set-foreign-key-in-form-with-class-based-views). The answer there seems like it would work but Django throws a ValueError

I have (2) models: Product and Procedure that are related by a foreign key. I want to have a link from the Product page to add the Procedure, and have the product FK (via its pk) automatically passed to the form. There are several thousand products, so selecting the FK manually from a dropdown isn't feasible.

```html
class ProductBase(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128,null=False)

class ProcedureText(models.Model):
    id_procedure = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4,null=False)
    text_procedure = models.TextField()
    parent_product = models.ForeignKey(ProductBase,on_delete=models.CASCADE')
```

I have a link from the Product details page to call a CreateView:

```html
<a class='btn btn-success' href="{% url 'products:addprocedure' pk=product_details.pk %}">Add Procedure</a>
```

which is mapped through urls.py:

```html
    path('addprocedure <pk>',views.AddProcedureView.as_view(),name='addprocedure'),
```

```html
class AddProcedureView(CreateView):
    form_class = AddProcedureForm
    template_name = 'addprocedure.html'
    model = ProcedureText
    #fields = ('__all__')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.parent_recipe = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        return super(AddProcedureView, self).form_valid(form)
```

calling in forms.py

```html
class AddProcedureForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ProcedureText
        fields = ('__all__')
```

and templating out to a standard form:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Whenever the form is submitted, Django returns a ValueError of the form:

Cannot assign "'28a3a242-06f6-464a-9b01-aa3fefa866ed'": "ProcedureText.parent_product" must be a "ProductBase" instance.

even though the rejected UUID is the one passed to it, and which is an actual, existing ProductBase instance. The problem occurs for any instance UUID passed to it.

Any thought on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `parent_recipe_id` instead of `parent_recipe`:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.parent_recipe_id = self.kwargs.get('pk')
```

You should then modify `fields` or `exclude` so that `parent_recipe` is not included in the form.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much!